# Should you manually batch packets in socket.io for scalable apps?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm making a whiteboard app with node.js and socket.io just for fun. However, for the purposes of this post let's pretend it has thousands of connections and I'm trying to make it scalable and efficient.

So let's say someone draws a brush stroke. This has to be broadcasted to the clients in the room so they can see it (list of points). To be real-time, each individual point as it's being brushed is being sent as a packet immediately.

My concern is packet overhead. These packets contain only an x and a y value and there are 40+ bytes of packet overhead. A single brush stroke might emit 50+ packets depending on its length. Not only that, but I believe Nagle's algorithm is disabled for socket.io (although I cannot find it mentioned anywhere in the documentation), so there is no packet coalescing. Even if it wasn't, I'm not sure how many packets would even be batched and sent as one.

I came up with an idea of using a queue such that all brush actions are enqueued and then sent as one large packet every 3 or so seconds and then smoothly played back on the client ends over an interval during the next 3 seconds. This way, there will always be a 3 second delay, but it will still be smooth and quasi-real-time and use much fewer packets (and thus substantially less overhead).

My question is the following:

- Is this already handled for me under the hood and I need not concern myself?
- Is this overkill even for a large number of connections and it's not worth implementing?
- Are there existing solutions that take care of this problem for you?

Comment: This is such a beautiful question, too bad there are no answers. I guess the safe thing to do is to just go ahead and implement the batching, that's what I'm going to do

Answer (score 0):

Not a socket expert, but if you are really connecting to a large number of clients and you want to reduce the 'chattiness' you might consider using UDP instead of tcp/ip for the client broadcasts. That should reduce your traffic a fair amount.

Rather than batching at a socket level, why not try to reduce your data a higher level? You could try concatenating successive grid coordinates into line segments or bezier curves for transmission and leave the sockets alone. I would think that this might be simpler.

Comment: The points are being connected via lines. Also, the guarantee of order and delivery of TCP appeals greatly to me. Even with UDP I'd still have to send the packets and I doubt i could write a better wrapper for UDP than TCP is.

Comment: You could interpolate your points in real time at a fixed time frequency to reduce the number of packets. Then once the user stops drawing, you could smooth out the lines by applying another interpolation pass.